# Angular 2 Electron - Consuming REST-API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, electron

I have an Electron App, which uses Angular 2 - in order to work i needed to modify   `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`, which is a relative path in the file system. But now the API doesn't work anymore (Webclient on localhost works fine, but not Electron Client).

I access the API via proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:4747/Ticketsale",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And the error message in the JavaScript Console of Chromium / Electron is:

```
file:///Users/myusername/folder/apps/officeclient_electron/office-client-darwin-x64/office-client.app/Contents/Resources/app/api/1/initialData    
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

How can i tell Electron to access the local resources via relative Path and consume the API via HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We enabled CORS on the Webserver and this setting allowed us to consume the REST-API from a different URL.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing for details.